# pyinstaller + pyqt5: could not find or load "cocoa"

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I think I did everything I could in the last 24 hours, but nothing seems to work. I have a python script I'd like to create a Mac OS X App Bundles from. I run `pyinstaller` with the following options:
`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --exclude-module matplotlib test.py`. Everything seems fine (the output is mostly INFO messages with a couple of dyld: warnings). However, when I try to execute the app it immediately closes. Attempt to run generated UNIX executable script `test` fails with the following error:

```
objc[24785]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both  /var/folders/gd/b5gj1m4x09b6jpb1llxk4vlr0000gn/T/_MEIOWkdrF/QtCore and /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[24785]: Class NotificationReceiver is implemented in both /var/folders/gd/b5gj1m4x09b6jpb1llxk4vlr0000gn/T/_MEIOWkdrF/QtWidgets and /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[24785]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /var/folders/gd/b5gj1m4x09b6jpb1llxk4vlr0000gn/T/_MEIOWkdrF/QtPrintSupport and /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[24785]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /var/folders/gd/b5gj1m4x09b6jpb1llxk4vlr0000gn/T/_MEIOWkdrF/QtPrintSupport and /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.9.1/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7f9dbdbb8400) is not the object's thread (0x7f9dbbd8bc20).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7f9dbdbb8400)

You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

A bit more info:

```
Mac OS X: 10.11.6 
Python:  2.7.13
qt: stable 5.9.1 (bottled) (via brew)
pyqt: stable 5.9 (bottled) (via brew)
pyinstaller: 3.3 (via pip)
```

The script `test.py` reads data from `xlsx` spreadsheet (`openpyxl`) and creates multiple `.docx`  files based on the provided template (`docxtpl`). It has simple interface `design.py` that was converted to `.py` from `.ui` via `pyuic5`.

What am I doing wrong? (or what am I not doing?) What can cause such problem?

---

My attempts to fix it:

At first, I didn't exclude `matplotlib` but it resulted in RuntimeError:
`RuntimeError: Path in environment MATPLOTLIBDATA not a directory
[26131] Failed to execute script test`

Also, I thought that the error with two sets of qt plugins maybe due to the existence of Qt4. I had a complete mess with Qt installations. There was brew's `qt5` (built with python2) and another macports's `qt5-mac` plus `qt4-mac`. I uninstalled  `qt4-mac` and deactivated  `qt5-mac`, but it didn't help.

I reinstalled `qt`, `pyqt` and `pyinstaller` to make sure that all of them were built with `python 2.7`.

Before switching to  `pyinstaller` I tried `py2app`. At first, I used `py2applet --make-setup test.py` to create a setup file. Again, build went normal, but the execution failed. Running from the console (`dist/test.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`) revealed that some libraries are missing: `ImportError: No module named docxtpl`. Adding pyqt packages `python setup.py py2app -A --packages=PyQt5` didn't help as well. Manually adding `OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes':['sip','PyQt5','PyQt5.QtWidgets']}`to `setup.py` did no difference too.

Another set of qt plugins are located in `/var/folders/` which is the location for per-user temporary files and caches. Don't know how exactly OS X manages this, but know that it's safe to clean it. So I did, however, cleaning `/var/folders/gd` before building or/and running does nothing. Cashed folder reappears and interferes with qt's plugins. Not sure, that this is the root of the problem, but have no more ideas how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less the same problem with pyinstaller 3.3 and conda python3.6.3 with PyQt 5.6.0. The .dylib files in `/var/folders/...` clash with the those in the conda installation folder. They kept reappearing even after I deleted them.

I finally got this work by specifying a temporary directory to the `--runtime-tmpdir` to pyinstaller.

e.g. `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --runtime-tmpdir /your/temp/directory --exclude-module matplotlib test.py`